# 3rd-libraries report errors during compile (using cocoaPods)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After I updated my mac to MAC OS 10.13.4.

Some of pods that I installed using cocoaPods, now could not be compiled properly.

There are errors from these pods when I build my project.
for example:
one of the pods that i used(RaptureXML), keep giving me errors such as 
semantic issues

1. Unsupported: typedef changes linkage of anonymous type, but linkage was already computed
2. Conflicting types for 'xmlTextReaderSetErrorHandler'

I'm sure that the there is nothing wrong with these pods, cocoaPods should be the root cause.

However, after searching online for solution whole day, I found  looks like the situation that I have.

I also tried remove and reinstall cocoaPods

But it doesn't work. These Pods still keep giving me errors.

So...is anyone have ideas? or should I reinstall my OS?

Answer (score 0):

I can say that there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the OS version since it is working for me. Try a simpler project with different pods.

If that works, then the pods you are using may have some compatibility issues. If it doesn't, you may have to reinstall your Xcode and other developer components.